Tkinter Window is empty on MacOS
The script is intended to create a window with a navy background and 200 yellow stars, but the window remains empty, and even the background color does not change. But on my friends laptop (he has Windows 11).
This code works:
import tkinter
import random

n = 200
width = 800
height = 600

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title("Hviezdne nebo")

canvas = tkinter.Canvas(root, width=width, height=height, bg='navy')
canvas.pack()

for _ in range(n):
    x = random.randint(0, width)
    y = random.randint(0, height)
    font_size = random.randint(10, 20)
    canvas.create_text(x, y, text='*', fill='yellow', font=('Helvetica', font_size))

root.mainloop()

I've tried to reinstall both Python and Tkinter - didn't help.
Tried this on Windows 11 - it did help

Have you tried installing Python downloaded from python.org?

This works fine on my mac. Are you using the version of python and tkinter that came with the OS? It's known to have issues. You should install a version of python from python.org or with homebrew

I have an answer here that might help; it outlines the steps needed to get tkinter up and running on Mac OS.

edit: running the file in zsh terminal instead of vscode defaults (for python at least) solved the issue

I am not sure, but it may be about how you named the loop variable _. This may have created a overlapping problem.

This is normal Python syntax, typically used in cases where you want to loop over something (like a range) but don't care about the value.
